# What should I do about water appearing in drain tile in my basement?

Tags: basement, drain

I purchased this older home about 7 months ago and having issues with basement getting wet. One area has an old clay tile coming up out of the concrete about 2 inches and goes nowhere but it will fill with clear water and seep out onto the floor. I have not been able to find the other end. I did run a commercial snake through it about 25 feet until it bogged down. I have a small transfer pump I use to draw the water outside and it will pump almost all day. This happens after a rain. Where could this water be coming from? Thanks Mark

Comment: You're asking where water comes from when it rains? Sump systems are common in basements anywhere outside the desert. A better question would be how to handle the water. Photos would be helpful in that endeavor. In particular, what does the basin look like and how large is it?

Comment: Ground water rises when it rains, if you have drain tile you know the home has had problems in the past. Running a small pump for a day is quite common in some areas it may take up to a week after a rain to empty all of the water out.